# Are HD wallet addresses accesible from just the public key?

Tags: hd-wallets

In other words, can I infer the infinite number of addresses of an external HD wallet (an HD wallet that I do not own) from just its public key?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't infer the infinite addresses from merely the public key of an external HD wallet by how the key-derivation functions work. However, you can infer that addresses are owned by the same entity from how the funds that are received to the addresses are spent.

Comment: Are you sure? This official ledger article says the contrary https://developers.ledger.com/docs/nano-app/psd-keys/#child-key-derivation-function